# How to access controls on hosted form in a user control WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

In visual studio how do you access a control on a form hosting a user control? For example, when text changes in a text-box in a user control, I want text in another text-box in another user control to change. Both these user controls are hosted on the same form. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Raise an event from your userControl, have the form or other UC subscribe to the event.  Begs the question *if they are that closely related, why are they on different controls?*

Comment: Can you be more specific? Why you need such integration between 2 controls at design time?

Comment: Plutonix, they are on separate controls because the user is able to decide which user control that want to display on the form. It could be either one or both. If both are displaying at the same time, the text needs to match.

Comment: Reza, it is a SOAP client application that gives the user two different ways to enter data to make a request.

Comment: If I need different UI for data entry, I prefer to have 2 controls with different UI, but I will use a single data source for them and handle the scenario using data-binding. If you bind both controls to a single data source, while you can have different UI, you have a single data and both controls data are sync. I shared a solution for your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need different UI for data entry, I prefer to have 2 controls with different UI, but I will use a single data source for them and handle the scenario using data-binding.

If you bind both controls to a single data source, while you can have different UI, you have a single data and both controls data are sync.

The answer to your question:

You can define a property in each control which set `Text` of `TextBox`. Then you can handle `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` and then find the other control and set the text property:

**Control1**

```
public partial class MyControl1 : UserControl
{
    public MyControl1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public string TextBox1Text
    {
        get { return this.textBox1.Text; }
        set { this.textBox1.Text = value; }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parent != null)
        {
            var control1 = Parent.Controls.OfType<MyControl2>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (control1 != null && control1.TextBox1Text != this.textBox1.Text)
                control1.TextBox1Text = this.textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

**Control2**

```
public partial class MyControl2 : UserControl
{
    public MyControl2() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public string TextBox1Text
    {
        get { return this.textBox1.Text; }
        set { this.textBox1.Text = value; }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parent != null)
        {
            var control1 = Parent.Controls.OfType<MyControl1>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (control1 != null)
                control1.TextBox1Text = this.textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly.