# C# How to change the value of a textbox on a UserControl on another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

How would I be able to change the value of a textbox which is inside another form's usercontrol from another Form.

Code on UserControl2 of Form1:

```
public string TextValue
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox2.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                textBox2.Text = value;
            }
        }
```

Code on Form2

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            int intselectedindex = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
            if (intselectedindex >= 0)
            {
                u1.TextValue = listView1.Items[intselectedindex].Text;
            }


        }
```

Comment: So what is the problem of your code?

Comment: It isn't submitting the text to textBox2 :(

Comment: It's better to not depend user controls to each other, but if for any reason you want to implement such dependency, take a look at this post: [How to access controls on hosted form in a user control WinForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803785/how-to-access-controls-on-hosted-form-in-a-user-control-winform)

Comment: You can use the same solution which I posted for your [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032716/passing-checkbox-values-between-usercontrols?noredirect=1&lq=1).