# Passing CheckBox Values between UserControls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to pass a CheckBox value from UserControl3 to UserControl1

On UserControl3

```
public void materialCheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (materialCheckBox1.Checked)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0)
    }
    else
    {
        //Nothing
    }


}
```

How would I add the value to UserControl1?

For example a button when clicked on UserControl1 will check if the checkbox is checked on UserControl3.

Comment: Your previous similar question answered in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025191/c-sharp-how-to-change-the-value-of-a-textbox-on-a-usercontrol-on-another-form#comment73141178_43025191). Why not trying the proposed solution?

Comment: that is textBox to textBox. that does work for that question. But! How does that translate to booleans.

Comment: As well, that solution did not work for form (nonparent) to usercontrol.

Comment: Have you ever seen how `BindingNavigator` works in conjunction with `BindingSource`?  Try to use such solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for communication between controls.

You have seen such functionality in interaction between controls like `BindingNavigator` and `Bindingource` where the `BindingNavigator` has a property of type `BindingSource` and each time you click on navigation buttons, the `BindingNavigator` calls methods of `BindingSource`.

To implemenet it for yourself, for example in `UserControl2` you can create a public property exposing the information which you want the `UserControl1` be able to check, then in the `UserControl1`, you should have a property of type of `UserControl2`. This way when you assign the instance of `UserControl2` to the property at design-time or run-time, then you can use exposed information.

For example follow these steps:

1) In your `UserControl2`, expose the information which you need to use outside of control.

```
public bool CheckBoxValue 
{
    get { return checkBox1.Checked; }
    set { checkBox1.Checked = value; }
}
```

2) In your `UserControl1`, create a property of type `UserControl2`. So you can use the instance which is assigned to it and find the value of `CheckBoxValue` property.

```
public UserControl2 UserControl2Instance { get; set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(UserControl2Instance!=null)
    {
        if(UserControl2Instance.CheckBoxValue)
            MessageBox.Show("Checked");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
    }
}
```

3) Drop both `UserControl1` and `UserControl2` on the form and using designer (or at run-time) assign the instance of `UserControl2` to `UserControl2Instance` property of `UserControl1`. Then when you run the program and click on `Button1` of your `UserControl1`, you can see the value of `checkBox1` which is located on `UserControl2`.

Comment: You have seen such functionality in interaction between controls like `BindingNavigator` and `Bindingource` where the `BindingNavigator` has a property of type `BindingSource` and each time you click on navigation buttons, the `BindingNavigator` calls methods of `BindingSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Work with delegates!

To read more about that click [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html)! For more check this msdn [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) out.