# How to change picturebox on UserControl from another UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

On UserControl1 I want to make pictureBox1 (on UC1) to be the same as the pictureBox1 on UserControl2.

On UC1

```
UserControl5 obj = new UserControl5();
pictureBox1.Image = obj.picturebox;
```

On UC5

```
public Image picturebox
{
    get { return pictureBox1.Image; }
}
```

This seems to not be working.

#### EDIT

---

On UC1

```
public UserControl5 UserControl5Instance { get; set; }
public UserControl1()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    if (UserControl5Instance != null)
    {
        UserControl5Instance.picturebox = (Image)this.pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
    }
}
```

On UC5

```
public UserControl1 UserControl1Instance { get; set; }
public UserControl5()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public Image picturebox
{
    get { return this.pictureBox1.Image; }
    set { this.pictureBox1.Image = value; }
}
```

Comment: [The documentation is clear on this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image(v=vs.110).aspx) - _"If you want to use the same image in multiple PictureBox controls, create a clone of the image for each PictureBox. Accessing the same image from multiple controls causes an exception to occur."_

Comment: [Image.Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.clone(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Well clone works. But could you show a way to put that clone into UC1 from UC5?

Comment: `UserControl5 obj = new UserControl5();` seems to be a mistake. Probably you have an existing `UserControl5` somewhere, for example on parent form or in the current `UserControl1`.

Comment: Currently you created an instance of `UserControl5` which is obviously different from the instance which you have on the form. Follow instruction [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43033933/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei I just released it isn't even pulling the picture from UC5. I removed the if statement and it gives me the null error even though there is an image in the picturebox of UC5.

Comment: `UserControl5Instance` in constructor will be not always.

Comment: Well then why am I not pulling the picture and it is saying it is null when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event on UC5 that fires when the image is changed and have UC1 subscribe to it.

```
public class UC1 : UserControl
{
    UC5 UserControl5 = new UC5();
    PictureBox picturebox;

    public UC1()
    {
        picturebox = new PictureBox();
        UserControl5.ImageChanged += UserControl5_ImageChanged;
    }

    private void UserControl5_ImageChanged(Image newImage)
    {
        if (this.picturebox.Image != null)
            this.picturebox.Image.Dispose();
        this.picturebox.Image = (Image)newImage.Clone();
    }
}

public class UC5 : UserControl
{
    public delegate void ImageChangedHandler(Image newImage);

    public Image image {
        get { return _image; }
        set {
            if (_image != value) {
                _image = value;
                ImageChanged?.Invoke(_image);
            } } }
    public Image _image = null;
    public event ImageChangedHandler ImageChanged;
}
```

This should update the picturebox Image on UC1 whenever UC5.Image is updated.