# Passing variables between user controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dataset

I a Windowms Form which holds a `UserControl`. That `UserControl` then contains two `UserControls` like this (all using panels as containers):

```
          Main_Form
              | 
         UserControl_1
         |           |
UserControl_A      UserControl_B
```

Now `UserControl_A` modifies a `DataRow` in a `DataSet` which must be shown by `UserControl_B`. The `DataRow` is unique with a primary key, which changes, if the row is changed in `UserControl_A`.

My question is this: Is there some way to pass the data row from `UserControl_A` to `UserControl_B`? I know it can be done by defining the `DataRow` on top level (`Main_Form`), which I have done with the `DataSet`. But is this really the only way?

(I know global variables could be an option, but that seems rather drastic for a somewhat simple problem).

> **Additional details**
>
> Basically what I want to do is making a calculator, for a customizable product. UserControl_A will be holding the controls to customize the product, while UserControl_B will show an overview of the selected features, as well as a price calculation. So when a DataRow is created in UserControl_A it needs to be readable by UserControl_B. Why do I use DataSet/DataRow instead of classes? Basically this is due to constraints from the team I am working with :-(. But wouldn't I face the same issue with a class, or is there a more clever way to pass that?

Comment: Can you explain bit more about the business use case? Also any reason you have to use dataset and datarow? You can use data classes and their objects and events and delegates to pass information between user controls? Specific use case would help us to provide you appropriate solution.

Comment: You can write your changing events. Main Forms can listen this end handle it.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Passing CheckBox Values between UserControls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43032716/3110834) or something like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803785/how-to-access-controls-on-hosted-form-in-a-user-control-winform).

Comment: I added some additional details. My apologies if this was too broad a question, I actually thought there would be a standardized way of handling this sort of scenario. But this could explain why it has been so difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best option BUT why don't you get reference to parent, cast it to "UserControl_1" and use something like getter to get reference too whichever UserControl you need.